# Help me extract a formula from data

Tags: functions, logarithms, arithmetic, exponential-function, exponentiation

I have the following datapoints, and I need a formula to describe the relationship between them:

```
╔═══╦═════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════╦
║   ║ A   ║      B        ║           C         ║  db(C)  ║
╠═══╬═════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════║
║ 1 ║ 70  ║ 0.3000000     ║ 1.58489319246111    ║ 2       ║         
║ 2 ║ 40  ║ 0.0300000     ║ 2.51188643150958    ║ 4       ║         
║ 3 ║ 1   ║ 0.0000010     ║ 3.98107170553497    ║ 6       ║         
║ 4 ║ 90  ║ 0.2000000     ║ 3.98107170553497    ║ 6       ║         
║ 5 ║ 0.05║ 0.0000000001  ║ 6.30957344480193    ║ 8       ║         
║ 6 ║ 2   ║ 0.0000001     ║ 6.30957344480193    ║ 8       ║         
║ 7 ║ 98  ║ 0.0010000     ║ 15.8489319246111    ║ 12      ║         
╚═══╩═════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════╩
```

On each row the formula is the same, if not then it's my fault I have mistyped the values, but normally it should be the same.

The 4th column is the decibel  10*log_10(x) value of the C column, notice the pattern there. The formula is a physics formula involving S/N ratio, but I can't find it so it has to be extracted from here.

I would like a formula that would describe the relationship between A,B,C , it is the same formula on each row, it should be not that hard to extract.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What do $S$ and $N$ represent?

Comment: @rubik signal-to-noise. It's a signal to noise themed formula, but I can't find it, so it has to be extracted from these values that I have copied from a nomograph.

Comment: And they aren't in the table?

Comment: @rubik no the formula is not there only the values in a nomograph. The values that I posted here I am confident about them, the formula is the same  in each row, so the relationship between A,B,C is the same in each row. The formula has to be extracted from this relationship.